# Proof of Authority Finalisation

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, parity, network, poa

Are there uncles/orphaned blocks in a PoA-based network? How do we reach consensus which is the real chain if the chain is splited/ we have a fork? Do you know any possible attack vectors on such types of networks?